# Remove global scope on specific query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I've a User and Post model. Both of them has a Global scope to get only published or unblocked user.

Now, I need to get the list of all posts even if the author is blocked.

This is the query that I used.

```
$posts = Post::withoutGlobalScopes()->paginate(10);
```

But since I've the author relationship with it appended, I get the author as null (due to the global scope if the user is blocked).

How can I remove the global scope of the author in the above query and get all posts (published/unpublished) along with the author (blocked/unblocked).

How can I do this?

Comment: use `::with('author')` before you call the `withoutGlobal`scopes()`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, nope, it has the same effect. The `author` relationship is in the array `appended`. So, it's always called.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar case and I changed the definition of single relationships (especially `->belongsTo`) to explicitly turn off the usually-global scope. If I had a reference to a Post and asked for its Author, I always wanted to receive the Author object, even if the Author was blocked.

```
class Post extends Model{
  public function author(){
    return $this->belongsTo('User')->withBlocked();
  }
}
```

But in my case I didn't do the reverse for one-to-many relationships (if I had a reference to an Author, and asked for Posts I usually didn't mean unpublished, and I'd ask for them if I wanted them).